# How do I remove(delete) all text that has superscript formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a large amount of text (almost 100 pages) while I was changing the font size I highlighted everything, changing the font size of the superscripts too. I actually do not need to superscripts, how can I delete everything that has superscript formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a simple find & replace operation.

1. In the *Find and Replace* dialog click on `Format > Font`:

   [image: 1]
2. Select *Superscript*:

   [image: 2]
3. Don't enter any text in the *Find what* and *Replace with* fields and simply click *Replace All*:

   [image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will likely need a word macro. I do not believe that there is any other way you can do this. To make a macro press alt+f11. Double click on thisdocument and paste this code

`Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "*"
  .Font.Superscript = True
  With .Replacement
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
  End With
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = True
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub`

into it and then click the little green arrow on top or press f5
sources:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/macro-to-remove-superscripts/733b2b38-5767-4a7c-a6ce-85d1d593bd23

Comment: "I do not believe that there is any other way you can do this." - That thread you linked to clearly says this can be done in a single document without a macro.